# Which preposition should be used with "lift" (i.e., elevator)?

Tags: prepositions, british-english

People usually go up and down the tall buildings_____the lift.

1. > by
2. > in
3. > on
4. > with

Which choice is right?

Answer (score 1):

I would choose #3, on. Depending on the context, though, you can also use "in the lift/elevator." Example: "I got in the lift to go up to the fifth floor."

With this sentence in particular I would rewrite it: "People usually go up and down tall buildings using lifts."